# Python - Selenium com Xpath não funciona nesse site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

Estou tentando fazer uma automação em Python para atualizar a página desse portal onde clientes colocam solicitações para fazermos cotação como fornecedores.
Ja fiz outras automações em Python com Selenium e webscraping e funionou normalmente, mas esse site específico não funciona nenhum comando de Xpath, eu consigo pegar o endereço normalmente, mas quando executo o código ele retorna a falha de que não foi encontrado o elemento procurado.

Esse é um código simples apenas para clicar na janela de usuário, que mesmo assim falha:

```
from selenium import webdriver

nav = webdriver.Chrome()
nav.maximize_window()
nav.get("https://www.vaatz.com/")

nav.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainframe.VFrameSet.frameLogin.form.divLogin.form.divLoginInner.form.edId:input"]').click()`
```

Após a execução, e carregamento do site que é um pouco demorado, o código retorna esse erro:

---

NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5 nav.get("https://www.vaatz.com/")
6
----> 7 nav.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainframe.VFrameSet.frameLogin.form.divLogin.form.divLoginInner.form.edId:input"]').click()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
1242             value = '[name="%s"]' % value
1243
-> 1244         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
1245             'using': by,
1246             'value': value})['value']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
422         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
423         if response:
--> 424             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
425             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
426                 response.get('value', None))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
245                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
248
249     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

***NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mainframe.VFrameSet.frameLogin.form.divLogin.form.divLoginInner.form.edId:input"]"}***
(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x00346903+2517251]
Ordinal0 [0x002DF8E1+2095329]
Ordinal0 [0x001E2848+1058888]
Ordinal0 [0x0020D448+1233992]
Ordinal0 [0x0020D63B+1234491]
Ordinal0 [0x00237812+1406994]
Ordinal0 [0x0022650A+1336586]
Ordinal0 [0x00235BBF+1399743]
Ordinal0 [0x0022639B+1336219]
Ordinal0 [0x002027A7+1189799]
Ordinal0 [0x00203609+1193481]
GetHandleVerifier [0x004D5904+1577972]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00580B97+2279047]
GetHandleVerifier [0x003D6D09+534521]
GetHandleVerifier [0x003D5DB9+530601]
Ordinal0 [0x002E4FF9+2117625]
Ordinal0 [0x002E98A8+2136232]
Ordinal0 [0x002E99E2+2136546]
Ordinal0 [0x002F3541+2176321]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74916359+25]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F087A4+228]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F08774+180]
(No symbol) [0x00000000]

Se houver outra forma de interagir com esse campo que não seja o Xpath e que não seja por poyautogui, sera válida, pois tem que rodar em segundo plano ou minimizado.
Sou iniciante e ainda tenho muito a aprender, mas após muitas buscas, não achei nada que falasse sobre isso ou alguém com a mesma dificuldade, talvez por esse site ter algo muito específico ou eu que não estou fazendo alguma coisa necessária.
Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

eu já tive esse problema antes, ele ocorre pois quando o selenium procura o elemento html específico, ele não o encontra, isso por que ele aínda não foi contruido na pagina. Você precisa usar uma função de espera, que espera até que o elemento seja carregado.

Você usa a classe WebDriverWait para esperar até que uma condição seja alcançada, e a classe expected_conditions que vai determinar a contição. Nesse caso, a sintaxe será: 'Espere até que o elemento seja localizado'

```
# Classe de espera
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# Classe de condição 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Espera em um navegador 'browser' por no máximo '10' segundos até que seja detectada a presença do elemento determinado no 'xpathcode'.
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpathcode)))
```

Para você não ter que digitar isso toda hora no seu código você pode transformar isso numa função.

```
def esperar_elemento(browser, xpathcode:str) -> None:
    """[Espera até que certo elemento WebElent seja criado no browser]

    Args:
        xpathcode (str): [Código xpath do elemento]
    """
    # Classe de espera
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    # Classe de condição
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    # WebDriverWait(browser, segs).util(condição) ->  Espera por alguns segundos segundos Até que uma condição seja comprida, por padrão essa condição é verificada a cada 500 milisegundos até que o tempo segs expire;
    # EC.presence_of_element_located(localizador) -> Verifica se um elemento já existe retorna um bool. O localizador (locator) é uma tupla (By.XPATH, CÓDIGO exPATH)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpathcode)))


# Chamada da função
esperar_elemento(browser, 'xxxxxXPATHxxxxxx')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta David, pois sua resposta me ajudou a chegar na solução, o problema não era sobre o tempo de carregamento do caminho, mas sim o frame em que ele se encontrava na página, na pesquisa para aprender essa função de webdriverwait, acabei me deparando quando ao frame da página que os elementos podem estar, e lá estava a solução, apenas selecionar o frame em que o elemento estava, através do comando

'iframe = nav.find_element_by_tag_name('frame')

nav.switch_to.frame(iframe)'

Comment: Essa aí eu não conhecia, tmj  ;)